# Align a plane with a triangle of vertices

Tags: transforms, constraints, geometry

I have two objects, a cube-like object and a plane. I want to change the location/rotation of my plane so that it contains three vertices of the cube (see screenshot)

[image]

Here is what I tried so far. I assign a vertex group (called triangle in the screenshot above) to the  three vertices, and added a "copy transform" to the plane, with the "triangle" vertex group as a target

[image]

As you can see, this method does not give the proper result (the rotation is off). Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried simply moving the plane with Snap to Face and Align Rotation to Target turned on?

Comment: So is this a modeling problem, or do you want to make this alignment dynamically, e.g. you're planning to animate the *Influence*?

Comment: @Psyonic, Snap to face works indeed, but I was looking for a more "programmatic" approach to do this. I ended up coding a solution manually in python. I will update my code with the code.

Comment: @maroxe the correct way to do this would be to post your code as an answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. In the end, I went with a "manual" solution in python. Code below.

```
def get_group_of_vertex(v):
    """Helper function to get the groups a vertex belongs to"""
    return [ vg.group for vg in v.groups ]

def get_vertex_group(ob, vertex_group):OP
    """Returns all the vertices in the group named vertex_group"""
    idx = next(vg.index for vg in ob.vertex_groups
           if vg.name ==  vertex_group)
    return [v.co for v in ob.data.vertices
            if  idx in get_group_of_vertex(v)]


def get_loc_rot(ob, vertex_group):
    v = get_vertex_group(ob, vertex_group)
    loc =  sum(v[1:], v[0])/len(v)
    norm = mathutils.geometry.normal(v)
    norm_plane = mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 1))
    rot = norm_plane.rotation_difference(norm).to_euler()
    return loc, rot, norm
```

To use it, you can call get_loc_rot(cube, "f1",) to get the location, orientation, and normal to the vertex group "f1" in the object "cube"

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible with constraints and just 3 vertices. This has mathematic reasons.

But it will work, if you put 4 vertices in your vertex group instead of 3.

[image]

Maybe a Blender/Mathematics Pro might explain it better than i do, and hopefully i understood it right and i don't tell nonsense, but here is my "assumption":

I think Blender does this:

Blender takes all vertices of the vertex group and calculates the sum of all normals for the resulting normal of the plane.
Blender takes all locations of the vertex group and calculates the average value of the sum to calculate its location.

e.g. the location of 2 locations will always be the point in the center between the two locations. like so:

[image]

e.g. if one normal is (0,1,0) and another (1,0,0) the resulting normal (direction) will be (1,1,0). like so:

[image]

As you can see in the picture (the blue lines are the normals) i first try to explain the location:

[image]

if you have 4 vertices of a square, the center point is in the middle . I think this is easy to understand.

Now to the orientation.

[image]

If you look just for the x-coordinates of the orientations of the 4 edges of the square you will notice that two point to right/positive, and two point to left/negative. So they cancel each other out.
Same happens to the z-orientation.
Just the y-parts of all orientations point to positive y. So the resulting orientation of the plane is positive y.

If you try to think about this with just 3 vertices you will know why it won't fit as you wanted too.

Comment: I never investigated the source, but it makes sense that the normals are calculated for the triangles first - since a normal is a vector perpendicular to the plane. Then based on that you can average it to get a normal for a face (which can be made of multiple triangles and isn't necessarily coplanar) and only then from that you can average normals of the faces a vertex is part of, to establish its normal. How otherwise would you calculate a vertex normal?  Either way, a triangle can be rotated to have its normal aligned with a quad's normal and vice-versa.

Comment: I misunderstood, indeed it seems you're right, yes, the normals come from the triangles, but then if you don't use the triangle's normal but vertex normals, it makes sense that discarding one of the vertices you should get a different normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible to do dynamically with constraints.  I'll use an armature with bone constraints, but you can use empties if you'd prefer.

We'll start by marking our three vertices with vertex groups so that we can reference them with constraints.  I'll assign each vertex to one of groups "center", "+y", and "-z".  These create a set of basis vectors, because the X axis is perpendicular to both y and z.

Now I'll create a simple armature.  Bone "center" will copy position from vertex group "center"; bones "+y" and "-z" behave similarly.  Then I have a bone "basisVecs" parented to center.  It damped tracks "+y" bone, tracking to Y, then locked tracks "-z", locking Y and tracking to -z.  This bone now describes the plane described by the three marked vertices.  We can parent a plane to this bone, and so long as we never move the plane in its Z axis, it will remain in that plane, regardless how that plane's vertices move.

In the screenshot below, I'm using a pair of floor constraints (+Z and -Z) to lock the plane to the three vertices, and I've given my cube a shapekey deformation to make it more clear that the plane is locked to the three vertices I've marked.  I'm showing the constraints used for basisVecs (adding a copy location, so that it doesn't even depend on parenting for anything):

[image]

Note that the rest orientation of our bones doesn't matter.  We're perfectly the defining the posed orientation of the one bone that matters via constraints, so we can give it a rest orientation aligned with world axes, for easy parenting of objects.